# Prevent Main page from refreshing after redirect

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm opening a new window on a button click using this javascript

```
protected void btn_----_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string response = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++)
    {
        if (mylist[i].id == ddl_idList.SelectedValue)
        {
            Session["selectedidObj"] = mylist[i];
            response = "<script>window.open('../folder/mypage.aspx','_blank');</script>";
            break;
        }
    }

    Response.Write(response);
}
```

The code works as expected with the object being passed into the page (open in new window)

But when the new window is closed, it causes the main page to do a quick refresh which is quite annoying to see.

How do I prevent the page from refreshing after the new window page is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Use registerclientscriptblock;

```
protected void btn_----_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string response = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++)
    {
        if (mylist[i].id == ddl_idList.SelectedValue)
        {
            Session["selectedidObj"] = mylist[i];
            response = "window.open('../folder/mypage.aspx','_blank');";
            break;
        }
    }

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Comment", response, true);
}
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this and it just appended a

"//]]>"

On top of my page and doesn't redirects